# Creating ID based on Name

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have large volume of client names I need to create unique code from.

I wish to use first 4 letters of the 1st word, first 3 letters of the 2nd word, and first 2 letters of the 3rd word.

```
4 EVEREST YOUNG
ABIC INVESTMENTS PTY. LTD.
```

i.e. unique ID would end up:

```
4eveyo
abicinvpt
```

Would someone be able to help me out with a formula that would achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you okay using VBA? Depending on your data, doing this in a formula will be complicated to account for all cases (like short words).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data resides in cell `A1`, try:

```
=LEFT(A1,MIN(FIND(" ",A1)-1,4)) & MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,MIN(3,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)-FIND(" ",A1))) & MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1,MIN(2,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)))
```

Comment: Lee, another great effort, but note where she indicates the unique ID for her example would be two words.

Comment: @Bandersnatch - thanks, however, I think the OP has misformatted her post which obscures the intention (I have edited the question, but still waiting review).

Comment: That makes much more sense. Excellent job, and great answer.

Answer (score 0):

This handles short words without causing errors or spaces to end up in the result.

`=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",G624)),LEFT(G624,4),TRIM(LEFT(G624,MIN(4,FIND(" ",G624))))&TRIM(MID(G624,FIND(" ",G624)+1,MIN(3,IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",G624,FIND(" ",G624)+1)),3,FIND(" ",G624,FIND(" ",G624)+1))-FIND(" ",G624))))&IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",G624,FIND(" ",G624)+1)),"",TRIM(MID(G624,FIND(" ",G624,FIND(" ",G624)+1)+1,2))))`

What a monster.

Examples:

```
4 EVEREST YOUNG               4EVEYO
ABIC INVESTMENTS PTY. LTD.    ABICINVPT
ABCDE FGIJK LMNOP QRSTU       ABCDFGILM
ABCDEFG I I I I               ABCDII
ABCDEFG                       ABCD
A                             A
A B                           AB
A B C                         ABC
A B C D                       ABC
AB CD EF GH                   ABCDEF
ABC DEF GHI JKL               ABCDEFGH
```

Edit: my first attempt had a problem that surfaced when I added more examples.